# Issue: Browsers Tend to Crash Each Time an Exploit Is Delivering the Payload to the System

Tags: flash, browser, exploit, metasploit

I am testing a lot of Flash exploits for variouse versions of Flash on Virtual Machines with Windows 7. Id say that 90% of the exploits I tested (on the correct version and correct browser) made the browser crash before the payload could be triggered.

I mainly used IE with versions 8 and 11 and Windows 7 (64bit).

Anyone having an idea or comment about this?
Like... settings... or... I dont know :/

Comment: **Why** are you testing these in the first place? Professional curiosity, or are you expecting SO users to be complicit in a shady activity?

Comment: @Clint 
haha white hat stuff: I am actually running exploits against an exploit detection system of an anti-virus companies software. Things where going well until I got to the Flash exploits: the detection system detects the triggering of the payload, but if I turn the detection system off, the payload cant trigger completely, because the browser crashes... I would guess that it is the exploit, which is unstable, BUT since this appears for A LOT of exploits, I guess i am doing something wrong.

Comment: Without knowing the exploits and implementation details (I'm certainly no expert) I'd say it's possible you're upsetting the browser process significantly enough to cause an exception (e.g. writing to memory the browser needs to run)

Comment: Yes thats what I thought as well, but this happens with all Flash exploits in the metasploit exploit DB and if this is the case, then MSF messed up when testing xD